# jquery wont work in a certain html styling

Tags: javascript, html

i try to make my code human-readable as possible and keeps my productivity efficient, i can easily track down errors, just as my below format.

i have an `<html>` inside a JQUERY. but this kind of format doesnt work for me. im sorry if my code format looks weird, hehe~

```
$j("#tool-abs").tooltip({html : true, placement : 'right', trigger : 'hover',
title : 
'
<ul class="toolclass">
  <li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>
  <li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>
  <li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>
</ul>
'
 });
```

**but** when my `<html>` are in one line, jquery works.

```
<ul class="toolclass"> <li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>  <li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li><li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li> </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you concatenate the code with `+`... when it's rendered It will be in *`one line`*...

Like:

```
var toolclass = ' ' +
  '<ul class="toolclass">' +
    '<li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' +
    '<li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' +
    '<li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' +
  '</ul>' +
' ';
```

Here, the result will be:

```
<ul class="toolclass">      <li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>      <li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>      <li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>    </ul>
```

---

But, if you want to keep the format, add `space + backslash` at the end of each line.

Like:

```
var toolclass = ' \
  <ul class="toolclass"> \
    <li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li> \
    <li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li> \
    <li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li> \
  </ul> \
';
```

Then, the result will be:

```
<ul class="toolclass">
  <li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>
  <li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>
  <li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use string contatenation

```
$j("#tool-abs").tooltip({html : true, placement : 'right', trigger : 'hover',
title : 
'<ul class="toolclass">' +
'  <li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' +
'  <li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' +
'  <li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' +
'</ul>'
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the literal newline, however, which comes close:

```
 "foo \
 bar"
```

for you code it would be like -

```
$j("#tool-abs").tooltip({html : true, placement : 'right', trigger : 'hover',
title : 
'<ul class="toolclass"> \
  <li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li> \
  <li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li> \
  <li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li> \
</ul>'
 });
```

Comment: You have an extra `'` on the first line of the `<ul>`, other than that this is what I would do.

Comment: Thanks, just a typo, I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing each line within double quotes and end each line with a +

```
title : 
    "<ul class='toolclass'>" +
      "<li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>" +
      "<li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>" +
      "<li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>" +
    "</ul>"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't strip javascript strings, to strip them you should add `+` between each line:

```
$j("#tool-abs").tooltip({html : true, placement : 'right', trigger : 'hover',
title : 
  '<ul class="toolclass">' +
  '<li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' +
  '<li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' + 
  '<li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>' + 
  '</ul>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract each line like this:

```
var $tooltip_html = '<ul class="toolclass">';
  $tooltip_html += '<li>Title   - the quick brown fox jumps </li>';
  $tooltip_html += '<li>Title 2 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>';
  $tooltip_html += '<li>Title 3 - the quick brown fox jumps </li>';
$tooltip_html += '</ul>';
```

and use `title : $tooltip_html` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the literal newline:

```
"firstline \
secondLine"
```

It is specified in ECMA-262 5th Edition section 7.8.4 and called LineContinuation

> LineContinuation :: \ LineTerminatorSequence

[ECMA-262 5th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)